# Cakephp Session lost when calling an action of one controller from another controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am using cakephp 1.3

I try to call an action of one controller in another controller and i was able to do it successfully. But when i tried to debug the session the session array was empty.
In Profile controller i try to call user controller

```
App::import('Controller', 'User');
$newUserCntrlObj = new UserController;
$newUserCntrlObj->constructClasses();
$profileArr = $newUserCntrlObj->userprof($userId,1);
```

In user controller userprof() i am getting parameters via import class but when i debug session array nothing is there. Am i missing anything here?
debug($_SESSION) = returns empty in userprof()

Comment: given var $uses = array(); and the problem was solved... and also we there is no view for action don't forget to add $this->autoRender = false; in action.

Comment: You do something totally wrong. You never call one controller from another. This means you are ignoring the MVC pattern and your app architecture is very likely a huge mess. Read and follow the MVC pattern when using a framework that featues MVC. If you dont do that you'll just produce an unmaintainable mess. No need for a MVC framework then.